# How to find updated "favorited" questions

Tags: bug, bookmarks, last-activity

On my home page, I can click on the tabs to see recent updates. For example, the "reputation" tab might have a blue "5" and the corresponding reputation change is highlighted in light yellow. However, I frequently see a number by my "favorites" tab (sorted by "activity") but no specific questions are highlighted. Is this a bug, a feature request, or am I just missing how to see *which* questions were updated?

**EDIT**

From the answer below, I think this is a bug under Chrome 35, and likely earlier versions as well.

Here's a screenshot of the bug in action:

[image]

Comment: Are you sorting by "activity"? I've just checked my favourites tab and actually see the opposite. No blue number at all but some are highlighted yellow.

Comment: I'm on Chrome 35 and it works fine for me. It might be something specific to your account.

Comment: Gah, of course I should have gotten a screen shot. I'll have to wait until a favorite question is updated and update this post.

Comment: I always see this bug, regardless of which browser I use.  It first appeared a year or two back IIRC; before that, the number shown accurately reflected the number of new/changed favorites.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I've also been having this problem for a year, and finally got annoyed enough to ask about it. Are you aware of any other questions regarding this issue?

Comment: I haven't looked.  Should really have asked about it myself, of course, but never got around to it.

Comment: @HarryJohnston As pointed out in the answer, your screenshot captures expected behavior. In my case, I have zero problems highlighted in yellow.

Comment: @Eric: ah, I'd missed the significance of animuson's comment; thanks.  OTOH, I'm sure I've seen it the other way around, i.e., the number shown in the header being *lower* than the number of highlighted items, or no number appearing at all despite highlighted items existing.  But perhaps I'm misremembering, or it's already been fixed.  If I observe it again, I'll post a new question.

Comment: I've discovered that the latter scenario (the number shown on the tab being lower than the number of items highlighted) occurs whenever I've already visited some or all of the highlighted items since they last changed.  That behaviour is entirely reasonable.  So there may never have been a bug, just some confusion on my part.

Comment: Just for the record, I do not think the bug I'm reporting is related to @HarryJohnston's comment. I don't check my favorites regularly unless they are updated, I only visit them if I receive a notification on my homepage. (In the weeks since I posted a picture of the bug, I have observed it several more times. However, it does not *always* happen.)

Answer (score 6):

The number beside the *favorites* tab indicates the number of questions that you have considered your favorite that have changed since the last time you viewed this tab. To see which ones they are, click on the *favorites* tab and sort by *activity*:

[image]

Now it should be clear which ones were updated/not.

Comment: It's not the number of *questions*, it's the number of *changes* on any of those questions. The number could be 10 changes, but if they're all on one question, you'd only see one question highlighted.

Comment: Then I'm thinking this is a bug under Chrome 35. I was sorted by "activity", but nothing was highlighted, and I've been frustrated by this problem for quite a while now.

Comment: @Eric: Once you've viewed that section (with or without having sorted under activity), the highlighting is lost.

Comment: @Werner Presumably the number should also go away, right?

Comment: @animuson: That's what I mention in my post; I assume you just wanted to make it clear.

Comment: @Eric: Yes, both the number and the highlighting goes away, just like with the reputation tab.

Comment: @animuson: Was it you that [declined my flag for retagging](http://i.stack.imgur.com/yWbrI.png)? If so, [this is what I see](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Nao7c.png): "Suggested edits are not allowed on non-tag-wiki posts on meta sites." (the same goes for as it is considered a suggested edit for low-rep users) That's why I'm unable to retag.

Comment: @Werner Right. So if I'm seeing the number but no posts highlighted (the first time viewing list after an update), this is a bug.

Comment: @Werner - I've added a screenshot to the question, demonstrating the behaviour that I find puzzling.

Comment: @Werner Should it ever be the case that the number in blue is *smaller* than the number of highlighted "favorite" questions? This is not the question I'm asking above, but I just noticed that behavior, which seems odd.

Comment: @Eric: I know that there are some inconsistencies in terms of the numbering, but I'm not sure whether it goes both ways. I'll have to wait until something like that happens to me in order to verify/reproduce it.

Comment: @Werner You can see what I'm talking about [here](http://imgur.com/SXIQK66).