# No edit privilege, yet moderators decline "suggested retag" flag

Tags: support, tags, flags, declined-flags, moderation

I am unable to suggest edits (including a change in tags) on [Meta.SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com). Here's what I see when I hover of the `edit` button:

[image]

Since it's good to be organized, I've suggested a retag of [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/257926/914686). However, a moderator declined this suggestion, saying I should do it myself:

[image]

This has happened before as well:

[image]

However, one such retag-flagging has been considered helpful in the past:

[image]

My suspicious is that it is the same moderator. However, I'm not sure how to handle such perfectly legitimate suggestions other than through flagging. Perhaps some guidance is acceptable here.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I did decline those partly because I forgot that suggested edits are disabled here, but the other part is that when reviewing flags, we don't see *your* reputation. Without opening your profile, we have absolutely no idea what privileges you actually possess.

I'm used to declining such flags on Stack Overflow. We get a lot of flags that don't warrant moderator intervention, some even retag requests such as these. I suppose I carried the habit over here.

Comment: So... a step in the right direction would be to mention one's inability to perform the edit oneself in the flag reason?

Comment: Thank you for the information @animuson.  I agree with Dukeling, to make the moderators' lives easier we should include a reason why we need them to do it rather than us.

Comment: @Dukeling - that's worth posting as an answer

Comment: @Cirdec It feels more like a minor edit to this answer to me, but I also feel that, given that I'm not a moderator, I don't have the authority to say that mentioning this information will make your flag a lot more likely to get approved (we can say what we want, but moderators will do what moderators will do).

Answer (score 9):

Moderators are reluctant to act as proxies for users who want to perform actions for which they haven't yet earned sufficient reputation.

Comment: (1) The moderation should indicate that, rather than suggest something that cannot be performed. (2) Some consistency across moderation would be equally helpful. (3) I'll suggest tagging-requests via comment from now on, until I have sufficient privileges.

Comment: Rather odd to have a feature that people are discouraged from using